# How do you do web routes in React and React Router?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, react-router

I have all my /api routes that require auth going through node but I want to also expose and have web routes that I can do in react and decouple from the server.

Is there a way to have react (or react router) handle web routes?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's basically what React Router is for. It'll act upon changes to the URL and instantiate the component that you specify in your routes.

Without React Router, just treat it in the same way as you would any JavaScript project: listen for history changes or hash changes and re-render accordingly. But with React Router you have a solution that integrates with React and provides utility functions and hooks to make life easier.

Comment: Right but that is to make the app completely single page. i can make actions but if I want to goto a specific route, I will get a 404 because the route is not explicitly declared.

Comment: .... what? Either use the HistoryLocation module of React Router or use the default route component. I'm not sure what you're asking.